# What to use thread or Services for android multiplayer game app

Tags: android

Need some help. So I am creating a multiplayer game app in android. Basically I have simultaneous thread running at the same time like UI thread, gameEngine thread, connect to server thread. Right now my app is using around 80% of the CPU resource. I think the cause of  this has to do with the multiple threads. Is this normal?

So my question is do I use services for connecting to the server? or thread is fine? What is typical CPU usage for game app specially multiplayer game app?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Services run even when your app is in background... i don't think thats desired for gaming app.. you can use Threads or Handlers instead...

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the server, I really recommend [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)